# Custom Theme Error - package name does not exist

Tags: theme, error, create

I'm having problems getting the 'custompackage' theme I've set up recognised in the Admin panel. I've been able to successfully update the Theme>Default>custom theme but for whatever reason the package name isn't working.

I've followed the steps on the Magento Commerce pages 3 times but have had no luck. The troubleshoot information suggests that maybe i've got the directory wrong, but I'm reasonably confident that I don't - screenshots of where they're saved are below. Is there any other reason this might be happening?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have also had problems installing Compass - is this possibly causing the problem?
(The error I get with this is 'marshal data too short (augment error). - Any help with that also would be greatly appreciated!)

Thanks!!

Comment: what is the name of theme you have enter, by default its "default". And from the picture it show a different theme name.

Comment: yes, it reverts back to 'default' every time i try to update it to 'custom package' - i was just trying to illustrate what i was trying to do with the image.
I've looked into all of the file structures and names and can't find anything wrong with the file folders etc.

Comment: i've also made sure the directory had permissions of 755 so I"m not sure what's causing the issue - any further help would be great!
thanks for both of your responses by the way!

Comment: try adding theme from System >> Design. If your theme is readable then it should be available in drop-down list.

Comment: ok you're right it doesn't appear in the drop down menu - this means it hasn't worked at all? - try again from the start?

(would problems with Compass affect this at all?)

Comment: can you try adding your theme in default package and check the result.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: So just to clarify - I"ve just put the 'customtheme' - the them, not package - into the default folder under skin/.….
and when i go into System>design and the 'customtheme' does not appear under the default package drop down

Comment: Please flush your magento cache once and try it.

Comment: just tried that then, but with no results..

Comment: You need to move the files in skin as well as design folder

Comment: hi, i've tried to do this now - the 'customtheme' folder is under the default folder in both 'app' and 'skin'.. it doesn't show under System>design - does this mean there's something else that's wrong with the setup?

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown from `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Design_Package::_beforeSave` if the this evaluates to `false`  `Mage::getDesign()->designPackageExists($value)`.

Going deeper in `designPackageExists` method you will find it returns the evaluation of

```
is_dir(Mage::getBaseDir('design') . DS . $area . DS . $packageName);
```

This means it looks for the folder packageName in `app/design/{area}`.
For some reason it does not recognize your folder.
Check for misspells or read rights.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i've looked back through all of the file names and can't see anything wrong with them, or the file structures. You mentioned something about read rights? - permissions?
i've just tried to change all permissions to 755 for the magenta directory - will this suffice or do i need to do it for all individual files?
(anything else you could suggest I try would be great!)

Comment: You shouldn't give 755 rights to all files and folders. Try t only for your package folder, as a test. Other than investigating why `is_dir(Mage::getBaseDir('design') . DS . $area . DS . $packageName);` returns false, I have no other idea.